# Magento 1.5.0.1 catalog_product_price index issue

Tags: magento, indexing

I am using Magento 1.5.0.1 with 600,000 products. Indexing is a major issue, especially catalog_product_price index.

1/ Towards the end of the indexing process a query is run DELETE FROM catalog_product_index_price . This has the effect of removing every item from our site so that the site displays 'There are no products matching the selection.' for all categories, the home page, search results.

2/ The process to insert from catalog_product_index_price_idx into catalog_product_index_price takes 10 minutes so we have a 10 minute window with no products on the site. I am absolutely certain this is a bug, there is no way someone intended for indexing to remove all products for a period of time - even if it was only 10 seconds this is not right for an ecommerce website

3/ For some reason the process of DELETE FROM catalog_product_index_price sometimes leaves a few products in the table therefore when the process of inserting from catalog_product_index_price_idx into catalog_product_index_price runs the indexer throws up an integrity constraint issue because of duplicate entries. This ends the indexing process and leaves the site with no products on. We run indexing in the early hours of the morning so sometimes we have a number of hours with no products on site if the index fails.

Does anyone know of a fix to these issues or a better way to update prices on the site that does not require us to index?

Comment: Id love to see a site with 600,000 products in it.  Can you share a link?

Comment: [link](http://www.worldofbooks.com) `www.worldofbooks.com`

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly well done for running Magento with 600k products, that is the most I have heard of.

The best way to work around this I think would be to override the indexing process so that instead of truncating and rebuilding the price index, it replaces line by line. It is likely that this would take longer over all but would resolve the issue of it having this window with no products.

One thing you could try is to replace DELETE FROM with TRUNCATE TABLE which might be more reliable for your "still some items in the table" issue.

Ultimately though I think you are going to be building a bespoke optimised indexer.